# PHP AJAX file uploader solution

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file-upload, upload

I did a lot of Googling and was not able to find a PERFECT file uploader suitable for my needs.

The uploader I mean;

- May have a progress bar or a status
  message.
- May support removal of files after
  being added to the list.
- May not start uploading immediately
  after the files been added.
- Must display error message for file not
  uploaded successfully
- Must support Multiple file selection
  in a single instance. (It should
  allow multiple file selection in
  browse window using hot keys)

[**phpfleuploader**](http://phpfileuploader.com/) was a nice choice for me, but it is not free.

Again I tried **[uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)** and **[SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)**. Both are nice with a progress bar. But to test error handling, I gave them a fake folder name for uploading the files to.. But wonderfully, both of the scripts showed uploading progress and uploaded message !!!  `:P`

It will be fine if somebody give me a nice solution / suggestion.

Comment: i use this and its free http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: Uploadify is great.. But it's error handler is not working.. I changed folder name in the script to a fake folder name.. But still is is showing success message and progress bar. Here is my code: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/427688/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[axuploader](http://www.albanx.com/)** 2.0 is the best option available.

Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 1):

Uploadify is best choice for you

http://uploadify.com/

it requires jQuery

Comment: uploadify is good, but it don't have an error handler. I used it and was fine. But when I changed folder name to a fake folder, reloaded and tried again, and it showed uploaded files successfully... :P

Comment: does it matter ? You will have to create your own handler which uploads & handles errors

Comment: error handler is there in the documentation... but not working for me.. :( I renamed `'folder': 'files',` to `'folder': 'files2',`.. but it showed success message and progress... :P .. see here http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onerror/

Answer (score 0):

i recommended to use uploadify

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: uploadify is good, but it don't have an error handler. I used it and was fine. But when I changed folder name to a fake folder, reloaded and tried again, and it showed uploaded files successfully... :P

Comment: they have handler when error, http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onerror/

Comment: its there in the documentation... but not working for me.. :( I renamed `'folder': 'files',` to `'folder': 'files2',`.. but it showed success message and progress... :P

Comment: hi @Haim Evgi, you there?? Got a solution?? :(